# NGINX redirect some special uri from https to http

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect a special uri from https to http use nginx.
such as: https://aaa/bbb to http://aaa/bbb.
And I don't change any other uri in this host.
I don't know how to do it and and wonder if anyone here could help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can add   :"return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;" in  a host on port 80

```
server {
      listen      1.2.3.4:80 default;
      server_name example.com www.example.com;
      ## Redirige le HTTP vers le HTTPS ##
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

and have an other server listening on port 443:

```
server {
  access_log  logs/example.com/ssl_access.log main;
  error_log   logs/example.com/ssl_error.log;
  index       index.html;
  root        /usr/local/nginx/html;
  
  ## Début de la config SSL ##
  listen      1.2.3.4:443 ssl;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
.
.
.
...
```